# Eclipse doesnt show output of JCWDE simulation in the console

Tags: eclipse, console, javacard

Recently I started learning Java Card development using eclipse v4.2 and the JCDE eclipse plugins with JCDK 2.2.2. (windows 10 64x)

I am trying to run a simulation with Jcwde. however when i run the simulation, Eclipse console does not show the output that says it has established a connection nor does register any inputs as commands.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTgee.png)

the console in eclipse should be looking like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eitlf.png)

If i go to the JCDK and run the Apdutool.bat after i start the simulation in eclipe. i can connect to the Virtual card; input my commands and run simple applets by sending command APDUs.

its also worth noting  that if the first command i type in the apdutool.bat is not powerup the simulation ends in Eclipse. (see next image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIbu9.png)

So Eclipse clearly is registering my inputs but no displaying them in the console.

also note that when i create a simple Java application that displays on the console like System.out.println("testing console"). the console displays the message with no issues. so the problem should be with eclipse console and the cmd.

i tried eclipse 4.2.3; eclipse 4.2 64x and 32x with different JDKs but all were the same.

Comment: Use the latest Eclipse instead of a version that is more than a decade old.

Comment: @howgler EclipseJCDE does not work on newer Eclipse versions.